# Acessar pasta especifica da galeria

Tags: android

gostaria de saber se é posivel eu acessar uma pasta especifica na galeria, pois tiro fotos com meu app e salvo na pasta dele la na galeria, mas queria que quando o usuario fosse selecionar uma imagem atraves do meu app, que ele somente tivesse acesso a esta pasta do app. Abaixo codigo que acesso a galeria.

```
 public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, SELECIONAR_IMAGEM);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use esse código:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/myFolder/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

Alterando o **myFolder** pro nome do diretório que você criou.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Mas testei e não acessou as imagens do meu app, coloquei o nome da pasta que foi criada mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

O que você quer é um filtro de galeria, para o usuário acessar apenas determinadas fotos (as do seu app) através do aplicativo nativo de galeria, certo?

Não tem como. Eu já fui atrás disso e passei bastante tempo tentando achar uma solução. Tem como abrir uma única foto com o visualizador nativo de imagens, e nada mais. Não tem como abrir um array de fotos com ele, por exemplo, nem abrir a galeria nativa com um filtro.

A única solução é criar sua própria galeria. Não é muito complexo. Você vai precisar de ir atrás de como gerenciar pastas e arquivos e de como usar gridview e, o mais importante, um imageloader para não crashar o Android(recomendo o Glide -- https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Lembre-se de colocar ponto antes do nome da pasta para prevenir o Android de fixar essas fotos na galeria nativa. (/.fotos ao invés de /fotos)